# Angular Js - Simple Program Showing Error (System Not defined)

Tags: angularjs

I am making a simple program in Angular.js to print a name. Alas, still it shows an error.

***HTML:***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="angularScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

***AngularScript.js***

```
// Defining Module
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

// Defining Controller
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.name = "Peter";
});
```

***Error:***

```
->  Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
->  Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Can someone help me out, with where is the problem?

Comment: you're writing angular 1.x but have angular 2 reference, either reference angular 1 or write angular 2 code. Easiest to fix your problem is the first alternative. But it could be a good idea to learn angular 2 as well

Comment: you mean angular2 is not backward compatible with angular1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct version of AngularJS script file.
You are writing AngularJS script of 1.4 but including 2.0.

Just replace your script tag with:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">`